# HTML CANVAS - Circle text is not showing properly and one circle text not showing top of the circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to create this pattern and I am using HTML canvas for creating this diagram. I am facing following issues -

1. In right side circle text is not showing on top of the circle. That text need to be displayed on top of the circle.
2. In other circles texts are not showing in straight directions. I need to stop the rotation of text. How can I solve this problem?

Please help me how to fix this problem. The code I have taken from different sources.

```js
var ctx;
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
function createCanvasPainting() {
  
  if (!canvas || !canvas.getContext) {
    return false;
  }
  canvas.width = 600;
  canvas.height = 600;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');           
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#B8D9FE';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#B8D9FE';
  ctx.translate(200, 200);
  drawChildCircles(4);
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2); //center circle

  ctx.fill();
  ctx.font = 'bold 13pt Calibri';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText('Hi', 0, 0);
  ctx.stroke();
}
  
function drawChildCircles(n) {
  var ang_unit = Math.PI * 2 / n;
  ctx.save();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    ctx.rotate(ang_unit);
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#B8D9FE';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#B8D9FE';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(150,0);
    ctx.arc(150, 0, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.font = 'bold 13pt Calibri';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    if (i==n-1) {
      ctx.fillText('data not showing top', 150, 0);
    } else {
      ctx.fillText('OK', 150, 0);
    }


  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#B8D9FE';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#B8D9FE';
  ctx.restore();
}

createCanvasPainting();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

**JSFiddle Link :**
https://jsfiddle.net/souravdikshit/nkfa97g6/17/

Comment: You are rotating the whole context before each circle so that's why the text is rotated.